# Wind flow diagram of a quadcopter

Tags: quadcopter, dynamics

I'm trying to determine the wind flow diagram around a quadcopter when it is in action. I looked up on internet but couldn't find any reliable source.

By wind flow diagram, what I mean is when my quadcopter is in mid-air, hovering at some fixed position, how the air is moving around it? All the directions are needed to be kept in mind, from ***top to bottom*** (vertical direction) and also the horizontal direction.

Comment: Can you post a picture (hand-drawn, even) of what you are looking for? What exactly are you trying to do with this diagram? It sounds like you want something akin to a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) or [streaklines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kK34LxQUtA), but I'm not sure what this gets you because the aerodynamic shape of a quadcopter [doesn't really matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eibyRBcmLvc&t=45s). The quadcopter doesn't generate lift, it generates downward thrust.

Comment: Yes sir i want something like streak-lines. Absolutely, and for both planes.
See the comment on the answer below to understand well. Your time is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The question needs some clarification, but at first thought here's a sketch of an answer.

The aerodynamics of rotors of a quad rotor can be simplified as independent from each other. Just to give a glimpse, here's a simple introduction to rotor aerodynamics, including near field flow directions, and average air velocity near (down) the rotor: [Helicopter momentum Analysis](http://s6.aeromech.usyd.edu.au/aerodynamics/index.php/sample-page/aircraft-performance/hoverclimbdescent-analysis/).

Keep in mind that this is a very simple (yet practically quite an accurate) representation of the real flow phenomena near the vehicle.

Things that should be considered for a more detailed approach:

1. existence and interaction of multi rotors
2. rotor - body interaction
3. unsteadiness (the propellers are in fact creating a periodic flow)
4. environmental changes (wind, pressure change)
5. control induced variations (even in perfect air conditions, if the quad rotor is moving a camera or weight, there will be control commands, changing the flow a bit)

Etc.

Comment: Yes.. First of all, Thank you very much for your answer sir.
That is actually what i am looking for but a little more detailed one.
Now the link above shows for only one rotor, i want to extend it to multi rotors and get the full streamline diagram of the whole quad-copter.
I am not actually from aerodynamics field that's why it is little difficult for me to work it on my own although i have tried much.
Also the picture shows flow diagram for vertical plane only, what i want is for horizontal plane also. That means i want flow diagram if observed from top plane. Hope this makes some sense.